# Was the "'Bama Boom" even recorded by infrasound or by seismic detectors?

Tags: atmosphere, measurements

The 'Bama Boom ('Bama is short for the US state of Alabama) is a term for some audible "booms" heard by many people in Alabama and now in Colorado. See for example the Popular Mechanics article [Mysterious, Powerful "Boom" Shakes Alabama](http://www.popularmechanics.com/military/aviation/a13728147/mysterious-powerful-boom-shakes-alabama/) and the Tech Times' [Mysterious Booms Heard In Colorado Leave Residents Baffled](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/216026/20171124/mysterious-booms-heard-in-colorado-leave-residents-baffled.htm).

*In this question I'm just asking about the measurements shown below from the CBS Denver News item [Mysterious Booms Around World Now Heard In Colorado](http://denver.cbslocal.com/2017/11/21/mysterious-booms-heard-in-colorado/)*, not about the "booms" themselves.

The second plot states it's a seismogram, but I can't tell what the first one likely represents. Could this be an [infrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrasound) measurement? The caption says that it's a "sound graph" but that's not necessarily a technical term.

[image]

**above:** "A sound graph from the USGS Lakeview Retreat near Centreville, Ala., shows a loud boom heard over Alabama at about 1:39 p.m. CST on Nov. 14. The cause of the boom is still unknown. (credit: NASA)" From [here](http://denver.cbslocal.com/2017/11/21/mysterious-booms-heard-in-colorado/).

[image]

**above:** "(credit: USGS and CBS)" From [here](http://denver.cbslocal.com/2017/11/21/mysterious-booms-heard-in-colorado/).

Comment: the first graph being infrasound seems to be a valid assumption. The sampling rate given in the header is 40 sps (40 Hz), which means the Nyquist frequency (the maximum frequency that can be properly recovered) is 20 Hz, which is the upper end of the infrasound range

Comment: @ye-ti-800 I'm guessing that the high-frequency cut-off for seismic data might also be around there as well, so I don't really assume either way.

Comment: yea that's right of course. Seems like there is a seismometer station called US.LRAL in Alabama. Has the right frequency range, too... http://anf.ucsd.edu/stations/US/LRAL

Comment: @ye-ti-800 typing "infrasound" into this search http://anf.ucsd.edu/search/ it looks like most/all seismic stations also have infrasound sensors as well. See for example http://www.usarray.org/researchers/obs/transportable/atmospheric Also found this https://ucsd.tv/search-details.aspx?showID=24911

Comment: right, but for this particular station the website only lists a seismic sensor. Since for other stations other sensors are listed as well, that might be a clue?

Comment: also: for the infrasound measurements they seem to have different channel codes. BHZ only occurs with the seismic stations. Might be specific nomenclature for seismic data acquisition http://scedc.caltech.edu/station/seed.html

Comment: I've just asked in Astronomy SE: [How do they know the TNT equivalent of the meteor explosion over Vermont?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41919/7982)