# Do sound waves from volcanic eruptions travel around the world?

Tags: volcanology, waves, barometric-pressure, air

Do sound waves from volcanic eruptions travel around the world? I recently read about the Krakatoa eruption and how sound waves from that eruption traveled around the globe 4 times and were detected by weather stations through pressure spikes in barometers ([The Sound So Loud That It Circled the Earth Four Times](http://nautil.us/blog/the-sound-so-loud-that-it-circled-the-earth-four-times)). What I'm curious about is whether this has ever been documented in other volcanic eruptions?

Comment: May be useful: [The eruption near Tonga was so powerful you could hear it in Alaska](https://www.alaskapublic.org/2022/01/17/the-eruption-near-tonga-was-so-powerful-you-could-hear-it-in-alaska/).  I'm still looking for a good reference to the multiple times around the Earth pressure wave (infrasound) measurements.

Comment: [2022 Tonga volcanic eruption](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-01-22/satellite-data-images-reveal-power-of-tonga-volcano-eruption/100773458).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you include low frequency pressure changes as would be recorded on a barometer as sound waves.

The 2022 [Hunga Tonga](https://volcano.si.edu/volcano.cfm?vn=243040) [eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2022_Hunga_Tonga_eruption_and_tsunami&oldid=1067233501) sent atmospheric pressure waves that were detected multiple times around the Earth.

According to the [Global Volcanism Program](https://volcano.si.edu/showreport.cfm?doi=GVP.WVAR20220112-243040):

> The sonic boom from this wave was heard at great distances, including
> in Fiji (about 500 km NW), within about two hours in New Zealand
> (1,600-2,000 km), and within about nine hours in Alaska, USA (9,370 km
> NE). The pressure wave was also recorded by infrasound and weather
> instruments worldwide as it circled the Earth, with instruments
> picking up the wave a second time as it arrived from the opposite
> direction.

In a tweet sent by [Michael Bunds](https://archive.md/rhT3W) you can see in the pressure each time the shock wave passed the weather station in Utah:
[image: Air Pressure at UVU and Passage of Hunga Tonga Eruption Shockwave]

Comment: slightly related and currently unanswered [Was the "'Bama Boom" even recorded by infrasound or by seismic detectors?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/12749/6031)